# Reduce lambda-expressions in WHNF

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, lambda-calculus, weak-head-normal-form

I have to reduce the following lambda-expression into WHNF, but I am not quite sure how to do it:

```
(λx y. x 3) (+ 4) (+ 6 7)
```

So, how do I do it? Call-By-Name Reduction?

Is this expression(other example) `(λz x. (λx. x) z) x` in WHNF yet?

Answer (score 6):

WHNF (Weak Head Normal Form) means that you either have a value (e.g. an integer) or a the expression is of the kind `(λx . e(x))` where `e(x)` is an expression that may contain references to `x`, so basically you have that the result is a function.

In your case the expression you have contains some applications that need to be reduced:

```
(λx . λy. x 3) (+ 4) (+ 6 7) = (λy . (+ 4) 3) (+ 6 7)
                             = (+ 4)  3
                             = 7
```

Note that in this case `y` does not appear in the body of the function, and thus the `+ 6 7` "disappears" during reduction.

---

No, `(λz x. (λx. x) z) x` is **not** in WHNF because the "top operator" is still an application. Note that the reduction in this case is a bit tricky because you have a free variable `x` outside and the `λ` also binds `x`. However we can first do some renaming: `(λz k. (λt. t) z) x` and now perform the reduction: `(λk. (λt. t) x)` and this is now in WHNF. Note that we do not reduce the application `(λt. t) x` because it is inside a `λ`.

---

to check if an expression is in WHNF you have to look at it as a syntactic tree. Let's consider the two examples above, and let's denote the application explicitly by `$`. Remember that the application `f x y` is equivalent to `(f x) y`.

In the first case the expression was:

```
                            |
              +-------------$-----------+
              |                         |
        +---- $ ----               +---(+)---+
        |          |               |         |
       λx         λt               6         7
        |          |
       λy       +-(+)-+
        |       |     |
    +---$---+   t     4
    |       |
    x       3
```

As you can see the root of the tree is a `$`, so we have to perform the application. In order to do this we must first reduce the left-hand side, which is again a `$` so this must be reduced first, obtaining:

```
                            |
              +-------------$-----------+
              |                         |
              |                    +---(+)---+
              |                    |         |
              |                    6         7
              |          
             λy      
              |    
          +---$---+  
          |       |
         λt       3
          |
       +-(+)-+
       |     |
       t     4
```

Now on the left we have a `λ` so we can reduce the outermost application `$`:

```
              |
          +---$---+  
          |       |
         λt       3
          |
       +-(+)-+
       |     |
       t     4
```

And now the root is still a `$` so we have to reduce that one too:

```
          |
       +-(+)-+
       |     |
       3     4
```

The root is a `+`, so we reduce again obtaining:

```
|
7
```

And now we are done.

In the second case we have the expression `(λz . λk. ((λt. t) z)) x` which becomes the tree:

```
             |
     +-------$-----------------+
     |                         |
     λz                        x
     |
     λk
     |
+----$----+
|         |
λt        z
|
t
```

Again the root is a `$` so we have to reduce it:

```
     λk
     |
+----$----+
|         |
λt        x
|
t
```

Now we have a tree whose root is `λ`, and this means that the expression is in WHNF so we stop.